# unable to test subscribe in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using Observable for event subscription but I am unable to test it

Here is my code

**Service**

```
export class EventService<T> {
    private eventSubject = new Subject<string>();
    eventSubject$ = this.eventSubject.asObservable();

    dispathEvent(name) {
       this.eventSubject.next(name);
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit{
    getSub: Subscription;
    constructor(private service EventService, private otherService OtherServece)(){}
    ngOnInt(){
      this.getSub = this.service.eventSubject$.subscribe(name =>{
         this.otherService.performAction();
         this.otherService.setVar = name;
      })

    }
}
```

**Spec File**

```
     let mockEventService :any;
     mockEventService = {
  eventSubject: jasmine.createSpyObj('eventSubject', ['next']),
  eventSubject$: jasmine.createSpyObj('eventSubject$', ['subscribe']),
};
     //some code
     providers: [{ provide: EventService, useValue: mockEventService }]
     // some code
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
     component = new TeamOvertimeComponent(mockEventService ,mockOtherService);
     ....
      it('should test ngOnInt Service var status', () => {
        expect(mockEventService.eventSubject$['subscribe']).toHaveBeenCalled()
fixture.detectChanges();
//
component.ngOnInit();
      });
```

I am seeing issue as

```
TypeError: this.service.eventSubject$.subscribe is not a function
```

I tried keeping them in before each but still issue exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a spy from the object that has the `subscribe` method, in this case the observable:

```
mockEventService = {
  eventSubject: jasmine.createSpyObj('eventSubject', ['next']),
  eventSubject$: jasmine.createSpyObj('eventSubject$', ['subscribe']),
};
```

The rest of the code you can keep the same, as far as I can see. And you can spy on it like this:

```
expect(mockOvertimeService.eventSubject$['subscribe']).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

---

To test the subscribe block you can do something like this (untested code):

```
mockEventService = {
  eventSubject$: { subscribe: jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake((cb) => cb('test')) }
};

otherService = {
  performAction: jasmine.createSpy()
};

fixture.detectChanges();

expect(mockEventService.eventSubject$['subscribe']).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(otherService.performAction).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(otherService.setVar).toBe('test');
```

Comment: Now, I am getting error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined` showing in spec file at `mockOvertimeService.eventSubject$.and.returnValue(of('string'))`

Comment: @Kartheeks you are mocking the entire thing, why would you look at the return value :)? You should just check if it's called or not by using `toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: I tried with `toHaveBeenCalled()` but still getting error like `Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Object({ subscribe: spy on widgetActiveSource$.subscribe }).
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: Strill getting the error as `Expected spy eventSubject$.subscribe to have been called.` Sorry I am new to jasmine so, having many issues

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you have at this moment? Because i see you use `mockOvertimeService` and `mockEventService`

Comment: Updated... Could you please check

Comment: Got it... I placed before calling detectChanges or ngOnInit()... Is there any way to test inside subscribe

Comment: To test inside an subscribe you need to update your mock to have the eventSubject$ be a real observable. You should then not use the `createSpyObj`, but the createSpy on the created observable

Comment: @Kartheeks I've updated my answer using a different approach than i mentioned